# Include double-quote (") in C-string

Tags: c, string

I would like a to define a variable string in C that contains the following set of characters: `a-zA-Z0-9'-_”`.

Therefore I would do it like this:

```
char str[64] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789'-_""
```

As you can see the problem is at the end with `"` character.

**Question 1:** How can I work around that?

**Question 2:** Is there a better way than my way to define a string like that?

**PS:** I didn't really know how to title my question, so if you got a better one, please edit it.

Comment: Escape the last quotation mark: `\"`

Comment: Escape it with the backslash: `"\""`. Note that with `str[64]` you have enough space for all your 64 characters, but not for a null-terminator. Depending on how you plan to use the string this might be a problem. With this initialisation though, specifying the length is optional so `char str[] = "...";` is valid and will automatically make the buffer big enough to contain the string + null-terminator.

Comment: Unless you've omitted some letters that I didn't notice that's 66 characters.

Comment: @HotLicks I copied & pasted it into Notepad++ which counted 64 characters: there are no v's in it (upper- nor lower-case).

Comment: Churchill would be disappointed.

Comment: Second question: it depends. What are you using this string for? Can the same thing be done using code? Can the same thing be done using its inverse -- a list of printable ASCII characters that are *not* in this list (about 30, with or without "v")? Can you use a bitmap array instead of literal characters? Can you use `ctype` instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the backslash: `"\""` is a string containing `"`

like this:

```
char str[67] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'-_\"";
```

added one for the implicit '\0' at the end (and put in the missing vV) - this could also be:

```
char str[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'-_\"";
```

and let the compiler count for you - then you can get the count with `sizeof(str)`;

How does it add up to 67?

```
a-z 26
A-Z 26
0-9 10
'-_" 4
'\0' 1
    ---
    67
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there a better way to define this string?

Comment: If you want it as a string - that is what you need to do -- if you you want a regex (regular expression) then you can express it according to the regex engine you use -- in C++11 there is `std::regex`

Comment: Should be `char str[66] = ...`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Or you could just omit the array-length, as it's optional with such an initialization. Also: there are no v's in it, so 65 is enough for the string + null-terminator.

Comment: @HotLicks - 67 editted to show math

Comment: @Kninnug I think the missing Vs are a typo since the question asked about A-Z and a-z

Answer (score 6):

Use `"\""`  (backslash") for putting `"` in a string