# How to place " inside a string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, escaping

I'm attempting to use a `strstr()` to find the first occurrence of a double quote ("), however, when I use this line of code:

```
pch = strstr(tmp,""");
```

It won't compile because I don't have a terminating quote. So I used

```
pch = strstr(tmp,'"');
```

which then tells me I have an error like this:

```
passing argument 2 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  pch = strstr(tmp,'"'); //finds the first occurrence and deletes the preceeding
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from assignment1.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:40:8: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 char  *_EXFUN(strstr,(const char *, const char *));
```

Any ideas around this or does anyone know of a way to use `strstr` to detect a double quote character? Maybe with ASCII conversions?

Comment: Try this: `strstr(tmp,"\"");`

Comment: I cannot find that information anywhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is given in any basic C book/tutorial. For your information look at C11's standard **6.4.4.4 Character constants**: `The single-quote ', the double-quote ", the question-mark ?, the backslash \, and
arbitrary integer values are representable according to the following table of escape
sequences:
single quote' \'
double quote" \"
question mark? \?
backslash\ \\
octal character \octal digits
hexadecimal character \x hexadecimal digits`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include double-quote (") in C-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458489/include-double-quote-in-c-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pch = strstr(tmp,"\"");` and it will work

Comment: `strchr` would be much better in this case

Answer (score 2):

To insert any special characters inside a string you need to [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) it by backslash. If the compiler sees the escape character it knows that the following character doesn't have a normal role. `\"` will notify that the double quote doesn't end the string like normal so `"\""` will result in a string with a double quote in it.

The full list of escape sequences is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Besides you can search with [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) but in case you just want to find the position of a single character then [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) will be much faster

```
pch = strchr(tmp,'\"');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to type `\"` instead of `"`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotes! like this:

```
pch = strstr(tmp,"\"");
```